# Getting null pointer exception at jDateChooser when application starts

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I am using jDateChooser plugin on netbeans. When application starts it throws     **nullpointerException** but when I choose date it works fine. The one and only one problem is it throws exception at runtime. Following is my code where I am getting exception:

```
String startDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(filterByStartDateChooser.getDate())
```

**Note:** I am using netbeans gui to design form.

Please solve my issue.Thanks

Comment: have u intialized `filterByStartDateChooser` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: what is filterByStartDateChooser?

Comment: @snabhat Netbeans is already initialized inside `private void initComponents() {filterByStartDateChooser = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();}`

Comment: @chinna_82 this is valiable name of `jDateChooser` field

Comment: `filterByStartDateChooser.getDate()` may be `null`

Comment: try to debug and check whether filterByStartDateChooser is null or not.

Comment: @MadProgrammer When I choose date from my jForm it prints correct date and works fine. But throws exception null at start time

Comment: @Kalathoki That makes sense.  The field doesn't yet have a date set to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen during initialisation. some function or actionlistener might want to read out the jdatechooser while it has no date set. to avoid this, simply add

```
jDateChooser.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance());
```

after creatign your jDatechooser.

Answer (score 1):

```
   String startDate = null;
  if(filterByStartDateChooser.getDate()!=null )
         startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dateFromDateChooser.getDate());
  if(startDate !=null){
            --------------
            ---------------
  }
```